# How to attach html element to angular

Tags: angular

I'm using third party js tool, which inject some html code into the page, as far as I know it using  runOutsideAngular.
I need to find one of the element of that generated content and inject my component into it.
What I'm trying to do is

```
const element=document.getElementById("page");

const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [],element);
this.applicationRef.attachView(ref.hostView);
```

But this code doesn't work because that "page" element isn't tracked by angular. (If I inject my component into any tag defined in angular template it works)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I finally figure out.

so basically what i had to do is to run everything inside the angular zone.

```
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      const element=document.getElementById("page");
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(PdfRedactionComponent);
      const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], element);
      this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);
    });
```

And now everything is working as I expected.